# forEach loop with async code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, async-await, frontend

I am making a function call 3 times with different arguments:

```
this.getContributorProperties('followers_url', 'contributorFollowers');
this.getContributorProperties('gists_url', 'contributorGists');
this.getContributorProperties('repos_url', 'contributorRepositories');
```

This function looks like that:

```
async getContributorProperties(propertyUrl, propertyName) {
    const contributors = await this.addLinkToContributor();
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
      axios.get(`${contributors[i][propertyUrl]}?per_page=100&${API_KEY}`).then((res) => {
        contributors[i][propertyName] = res.data.length;
      });
    }
    return contributors;
}
```

It loops through an array of contributors (object type) and makes an API call for each one of them. I need to make 3 API calls for each one of them hence the three calls at the beginning.
In order to DRY up my code I wanted to make a forEach loop like so:

```
[
      ['followers_url', 'contributorFollowers'],
      ['gists_url', 'contributorGists'],
      ['repos_url', 'contributorRepositories'],
    ].forEach(this.getContributorProperties);
```

forEach loop is in `componentDidMount()`
When I make 3 calls it works ok. But when I do forEach I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLinkToContributor' of undefined
```

How do I make it work?

BONUS: How do I then assign those key-value pairs to each object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) and/or [*How does the "this" keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) are for **runnable** code. For just code blocks, use the `{}` button (or Ctrl+K or just indent each line four spaces).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [*How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) and/or [*How does the "this" keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) for why you had that specific error message.

But fundamentally, you wouldn't want to just pass that function into `forEach` anyway, since `forEach` doesn't pass that function what it wants.

Instead, just use an arrow function:

```
[
  ['followers_url', 'contributorFollowers'],
  ['gists_url', 'contributorGists'],
  ['repos_url', 'contributorRepositories'],
].forEach(pair => this.getContributorProperties(pair[0], pair[1]).catch(err => {/*...handle error...*/});
```

Note the error handling; we don't want unhandled rejections, and `forEach` doesn't do anything to propagate them to the caller.

---

It seems odd, though, not to use the return value for anything. Perhaps `map` and `Promise.all`:

```
const results = await Promise.all([
  ['followers_url', 'contributorFollowers'],
  ['gists_url', 'contributorGists'],
  ['repos_url', 'contributorRepositories'],
].map(pair => this.getContributorProperties(pair[0], pair[1])));
```

...being sure to handle errors if the caller won't.

---

Please note there are two bugs in your `getContributorProperties` function:

1. It doesn't wait for the `axios.get` to complete before returning (`async` functions don't auto-`await` promises, you have to be explicit)
2. It doesn't handle rejections of the promise returned by `axios.get`

I'm also curious if repeating the call to `this.addLinkToContributor` three times is correct, and whether it may be wasteful the second two times.

In a comment you've asked:

> `Results` are 3 arrays of the same objects (contributors) with just one property changed each. So one array has contributors with gists, another with followers, etc. Do I now somehow concatenate them or is it better to do that in `getContributorProperties` function?

That would be my instinct. Something like:

```
async getContributorProperties(properties) {
    const contributors = await this.addLinkToContributor();
    return Promise.all(contributors.map(contributor =>
      Promise.all(properties.map(property =>
        axios.get(`${contributor[property.url]}?per_page=100&${API_KEY}`).then(res => {
          contributor[property.name] = res.data.length;
        })
      ));
    ));
}
```

called like this:

```
const results = await this.getContributorProperties([
  {url: 'followers_url', name: 'contributorFollowers'},
  {url: 'gists_url',     name: 'contributorGists'},
  {url: 'repos_url',     name: 'contributorRepositories'}
]);
```

---

*(We really need that [`await.all` concept](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/how-about-awaiting-arrays) so that the above isn't mixing its metaphors...)*

Comment: `Results` are 3 arrays of the same objects (contributors) with just one property changed each. So one array has contributors with gists, another with followers, etc. Do I now somehow concatenate them or is it better to do that in `getContributorProperties` function?

Comment: @AdamMarczyk: I've added to the answer, addressing that and a couple of other things.

Comment: Does that address the first bug?

   ` async function contributorsLoop() {
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1){
    <loop here>
      }
    }
    const res = await contributorsLoop();
    return res;
  }`

Comment: @AdamMarczyk: That would depend entirely on what's in `<loop here>`. My solution above does, though, while keeping everything in parallel.

Comment: What if I don't want to map over all contributors? There are about 5k of them. What can I do to make an API call just for, say, 10 of contributors?

Comment: @AdamMarczyk: `contributors.slice(0, 10).map(...)`